# Python PyInstaller Ubuntu Troubles

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have been searching for tutorials on how to use pyinstaller and cant find that one that i can follow. I have been researching this for hours on end and cant find anything that helps me. I am using Linux and was wondering if anyone can help me out form the very begging, because there is not one part i understand about this. I also have three files that make up one program, and am also using Tkinter so i dont know if that makes it more difficult.

Comment: The reason there aren't many tutorials on how to do this on Linux is because there is not much point to do this on Linux, as the actual Python files can be turned into a package with a set of dependencies and everything. Perhaps you should try that instead; the PyInstaller approach is only worth it if you have a valid reason not to use packages (and such reasons do exist).

Comment: I see, well if i was going to make an app for windows, would i need to use pyinstaller or is there a short cut for that to?

Comment: On Windows you would use it, because Windows lacks package management, yes.

Comment: OK thank you You've been a a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is reposted from my comment on the question, so that this question may be marked as answered (assuming OP is satisfied with this answer). It was originally posted as a comment because it does not answer the question directly.

> The reason there aren't many tutorials on how to do this on Linux is
>   because there is not much point to do this on Linux, as the actual
>   Python files can be turned into a package with a set of dependencies
>   and everything. Perhaps you should try that instead; the PyInstaller
>   approach is only worth it if you have a valid reason not to use
>   packages (and such reasons do exist).